# why does this not print the string?

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, c-strings, string-literals

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  
  const char *adj[] = {"swag","nice","asparagus","ugly"};

  for (int i=0;i<sizeof(adj); i++)
    printf("you are extremely %s\n", *adj[i]);

}
```

i'm actually new to C and i'm trying test programs to learn, in this case i was hoping for it to print the name a few times with all the adjectives, but it doesn't when using `%s` in the last print, if i use `%c` it will only print the first letter of the string

tried swapping `%c` and `%s`, but neither work, `%c` prints only the 1st letter, `%s` prints nothing

Comment: The compiler told you why. "error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]" Please use these options when compiling: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) Also `sizeof(adj)` is wrong, it must be `sizeof(adj) / sizeof(*adj)`.

Comment: If it helps, `*adj[i]` is equivalent to `adj[i][0]`, but you really want `adj[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
sizeof(adj)
```

or simply

```
sizeof adj
```

will give you the size of the array in bytes. The size of the array in bytes is not necessarily identical to the number of elements in the array. If the size of an element of the array is larger than a single byte, then the size of the array in bytes will be larger than the number of elements in the array.

Therefore, in order to determine the number of elements in an array, you must divide the total size of the array by the size of a single element of the array. You can do this using the following expression:

```
sizeof adj / sizeof *adj
```

For the reasons stated above, you should change the line

```
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(adj); i++)
```

to:

```
for ( int i=0; i < sizeof adj / sizeof *adj; i++ )
```

Another issue is that the line

```
printf("you are extremely %s\n", *adj[i]);
```

is wrong. The `%s` `printf` format specifier requires that you pass as a function argument a `char *` that points to the null-terminated string that is to be printed. However, that is not what you are doing. You are instead passing as the function argument the first character that is to be printed, which is of type `char`. Because you are passing a `char` instead of a `char *` as a function argument to `printf`, your program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For this reason, you should remove the `*`, so that the line looks like this:

```
printf( "you are extremely %s\n", adj[i] );
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters `sizeof( adj )` is equal to `4 * sizeof( char * )` where `4` is the number of initializers. If `sizeof( char * )` is equal to for example `8` then the for loop looks in fact like

```
for (int i=0;i < 32; i++)
```

while the array contains only `4` elements.

To get the number of elements in the array you need to use the expression `sizeof( adj ) / sizeof( *adj )` that is the same as `sizeof( adj ) / sizeof( char * )`.

And as the expression has the type `size_t` it is much better to declare the variable `i` also as having the type `size_t`

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( adj ) / sizeof( *adj ); i++ )
```

And the argument of the call of `printf` shall be a pointer to a string while the expression `*adj[i]` has the type `const char`.

That is you need to write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( adj ) / sizeof( *adj ); i++ )
{
    printf( "you are extremely %s\n", adj[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to do it

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
  
  const char *adj[] = {"swag","nice","asparagus","ugly"};

  for (int i=0;i<sizeof(adj)/sizeof(*adj); i++)
    printf("you are extremely %s\n", adj[i]);
}
```

outputs

```
you are extremely swag
you are extremely nice
you are extremely asparagus
you are extremely ugly
```

`sizeof(adj)` returns the total size of the pointers. There are 4 pointers each is of 32bit or 64bit, so the number of elements have to be obtained by `sizeof(adj)/sizeof(*adj)` i.e., total size in bytes/ size of one pointer.

The second error in your code is in the printf, you have to print the string pointed by the char pointer not the single char.

Comment: *'each is of 32 bit'* – entirely depends on the underlying system! On most of mine they are 64 bit instead. Actually size of bits is not even the relevant measure here, it's the size in `char`s instead (explicitly not saying 'bytes', as these might be associated with a fixed size of 8 bits while `char` can have more...).

Comment: *'pointer to char pointer'* – that would be: `char* ptr; printf("%p", &ptr)` – `*adj[i]` in contrast is a single `char`, first one in each string.